# Crystal Reports Error - Incorrect Syntax Error

Tags: sql, t-sql, crystal-reports, odbc, report

I have an existing Crystal Report connected to a Stored proc on SQL Server 2012. OLE DB ADO - Provider SQLNCLI11 The report runs fine from the Local server.

Crystal SQL:

```
"Database"."dbo"."StoredProcName";1 N'2008474', {d '2019-04-01'}
```

When i go to deploy on another Server I receive an error message.

```
Failed to Retrieve data from the database. Details ADo Error: ox
Source MS SQL Server native client 11.0
Incorrect Syntax near the keyword "Convert"
```

Crystal SQL:

```
"Database"."dbo"."StoredProcName";1 N'2008206', CONVERT(DATETIME, '04-09-2019', 110)
```

Both machines have SQL Server Native Client 11 Drivers installed.

Clearly something with the hardware. Any advise is appreciated.

Thank you
Will

Comment: Doesn't sound like anything to do with the hardware. Is the same version of Crystal Reports running on both machines? Compare the Registry trees on each machine. I think you'll find some differences, which are associated with the syntax/dialect Crystal uses when building SQL queries against specified providers/drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I've had something similar when moving to the newer Crystal developer instance and a newer database version (2016). In this case I had to use the OLEDB connection type rather then the Native Client. I don't know if this will help you but at least you can rule it out after testing.